# Scrollbars fails to appear in two flexbox containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two containers that are laid out side by side with a common header and footer. Everything has been done with the flex layout available in newer browsers (*note: my code is using the webkit specific directives*).

The problem is that I can't make scrollbars appear in both containers if the browser window is resized. All I get is one scrollbar that scrolls everything. How can accomplish this?

[JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/AsElIGi/6/edit).

The HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search">Search bar</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="search-results vertical pane">
        <strong>Search results</strong>
        <ul>
          <li>Item</li>
          ...
          <li>Item</li>
        </ul>          
      </div>
      <div class="content vertical pane">
        <strong>Item</strong>
        <ul>
          <li>Item detail</li>
          ...
          <li>Item detail</li>
        </ul>          
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <strong>Footer</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is here:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.main  {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
}

.vertical {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.pane  {
  width: 50%;
}

.search {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-flex: 0.01;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-flex: 0.01;
}

.search-results {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add a height/max-height, higher than the content to the container.

For example:

```
.vertical {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/D3gc2/)

Answer (score 0):

After even more research, I found out that the `main` class is the real culprit here, adding `min-height: 0` makes it take up space as it should (this is a hack, but it seems to be a very widely used hack). Adding `overflow-y: scroll` made the scrollbars work as they should.

[JSBin here for Chrome 24](http://jsbin.com/AsElIGi/7/edit).

Update: it works much better in Chrome 32. See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AsElIGi/9/edit).